# Как сделать выборку уникальных значений столбца postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы, они обеденяються через join,

articles - поля id, model_id, city_id, region_id

models - id, name, brand_id

join происходит articles.model_id <-> models.id

Вопрос - как в таблице article выбрать только уникальные значения поля city_id

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [SELECT DISTINCT](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/sql-select#SQL-DISTINCT)

```
SELECT DISTINCT city_id
FROM articles a
  INNER JOIN models m ON a.model_id = m.id;
```

Пример для тестирования:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.col1
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS col1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2
) t
```